# div with fixed position cannot be scroled

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-position

I have  `<div>` with `position:fixed` and I want to have a scroll for that div when browser is resized. I already tried `overflo:auto` and other but is not working. 
If someone can help me with this ...Thank's.

```
<div class="div1">
   <span class="l">1</span>
   <span class="l">2</span>
   <span class="l">3</span>
  <span class="l">4</span>
  <span class="r">4</span>
  <span class="r">3</span>
  <span class="r">2</span>
  <span class="r">1</span>
</div>
```

css

```
 .div1{
      background:lime;
      width:45pc;
      height:50px;
      position: fixed;
      overflow-x: scroll;
    }

    .l{
      float: left;
    }

    .r{
      float:right;
    }
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ksb2W/158/

Comment: I'm not quite sure about your question; You want the div always to be the same `width`, and when this `width` is larger than the webpage, you want the scrollbar to appear?

Comment: @leMoisela yes, this is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another div inside

```
<div class="div1">
  <div class="ins">
   <span class="l">1</span>
   <span class="l">2</span>
   <span class="l">3</span>
  <span class="l">4</span>
  <span class="r">4</span>
  <span class="r">3</span>
  <span class="r">2</span>
  <span class="r">1</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and some changes to css.

```
.div1{
  background:lime;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-x: scroll;

}
.ins{
  min-width:45pc;
  height:50px;

}

.l{
  float: left;
}

.r{
  float:right;
}
```

here's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ksb2W/189/

Answer (score 1):

Change your `width:45pc;` to `width:45px;`. Then everything works as expected.

When you use pica then your width is 16 * 45 px (720px), because 1pc=16px.
If you want to keep pc as unit you need to use in your case `width:2.8125pc;`

Comment: pc=pica (1 pc is the same as 12 points) px=pixels (a dot on the computer screen)

Comment: @burebistaruler Yes, I know. But apart from the fact that I have never seen a use of using pc or pt instead of px, it still fixes the problem. By the way. 1pc = 12 pt ~ 16px. So you give a width of 45 * 16 px. If you want to stay with pc, then you must make the math for the correct width.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you think I'm wrong, then explain it at least.

Comment: Because this is not fixing my question! ... but ok if you want an Upvote!

Comment: @burebistaruler no, that is not the point. Your problem is fixed, because you don't understand the measurement of pica. And I don't need your upvote, I just like to have explained why I get downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you type a c instead of an x, so change `width:45pc;` to `width:45px;`. That should fix it.

Comment: pc=pica (1 pc is the same as 12 points) px=pixels (a dot on the computer screen)

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that, sorry!

Comment: I don't understand why this answer gets upvoted, while mine gets downvoted. But ok.